# RuntimeWarning: A class named 'Individual' has already been created and it will be overwritten

Tags: python

I have code that uses a `deap` library.  This code has been running in a virtual environment without issue without any issue for a while.  I then copy the whole environment to a new virtual envronemnt and run the code and I start getting a run time error:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/deap/creator.py:141: RuntimeWarning: A class named 'Individual' has already been created and it will be overwritten. Consider deleting previous creation of that class or rename it.
>
> RuntimeWarning)

The data used in the old and new environments is exactly the same and the results returned look the same looks the same as well.  I can't find anything that suitably describes why this run time error occurs - why might be happening?

Comment: Please refer below link and see if it resolves your problem.https://github.com/DEAP/deap/issues/108

Comment: Not really, my issue is that the code works fine in my old environment but not in the new why would that be?

Comment: Could you provide some more details and/or code to make things more clear?

Comment: What about the message: "*A class named 'Individual' has already been created and it will be overwritten. Consider deleting previous creation of that class or rename it.*". Have you tried the suggestion, already? It seems for me (but I do not know deap) that there is a code generator which creates python classes for you. This may conflict with already compiled classes or whatever. It is really hard to say if you don't provide more information as already mentioned in other comments.

Comment: **HOW** did you copy the environment?  `conda clone` or `pip install -r requirements.txt` or did you literally just copy the folder?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is about what could be different between the two versions. I would politely suggest that you would need to provide more information to the user community if you want a useful answer. Off the top of my head, here are a few possibilities:

1. different versions of python
2. different versions of deap library
3. different variables in the global namespace

My best guess is option 3. If you look at https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/master/deap/creator.py line 141, you'll see the following code:

```
if name in globals():
    warnings.warn("A class named '{0}' has already been created and it "
                      "will be overwritten. Consider deleting previous "
                      "creation of that class or rename it.".format(name),
                      RuntimeWarning)
```

So when you run `create`, the function calls the `globals()` function and looks for any variables already named what you want to name your class. In your case, there's a pre-existing class called `Individual`. To say why for sure would likely require a look at your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the actual answer:

When you run `creator.create("Individual", ...)`, it creates the `creator.Individual` class.

If you re-run `creator.create("Individual", ...)`, it complains that the class exists.

Either delete the whole `creator` object, or just that class. In other words:

```py
try:
    del creator
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

or

```py
try:
    del creator.Individual
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

Place the del code before `creator.create(...)`

Answer (score -1):

The DEAP library creates an Individual class when you run it. If you run it twice, then it will overwrite the previously defined Individual class. In your new environment, somewhere along the way, you are running DEAP twice.

The different behaviour with respect to print out demonstrates that your environments are not in fact identical. Probably version of DEAP is different. You can check the `deap.__version__` variable and compare.